# How do I copy zfs partitions from one disk to a smaller disk?

Tags: backup, zfs, snapshot

I'm trying to shrink a zfs partition. I've read that you can't do this directly. The only way is to mirror the partition to a temporary disk first, delete and then re-create new, smaller partitions in place of the original, then copy the contents back.

The source partitions identify as partition type "Solaris Boot" and "Solaris Root", both contents are zfs. The first has a zpool called "bpool", and the 2nd called "rpool". I can create new pools on the

1. I created new partitions on the temporary disk, but cannot set the partition types to "Solaris Boot/Root" using gparted. Is there a way to do this?
2. I tried `zfs send -R bpool | zfs receive -F tempbpool` and similarly for the rpool. These commands complete immediately. I have 0 confidence that the terabytes of data were actually copied to the temporary disk.
3. I also tried creating a snapshot, bpool@today. The send/receive also completed immediately.
4. Some of the zfs documentation hints that I can copy these partitions while the original pools are active. Is that true? A snapshot in time is probably good.

So, what's the right way to copy the contents of these disks?

I really need to shrink the zfs partitions so that I can grow the 1st partition on the disk. If there's a better way, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm fairly certain you need a snapshot first, since the data needs to be frozen.

Comment: You don't need to create temporary zfs pools - you can backup to a file. What happens if you try and send the snapshot to a compressed file? `zfs send -R bpool@today > gzip /tmp/bpool.gz`

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: This answer does not take into account if you have special ZFS boot partitions. The configuration of a restored zpool to be used as a boot partition or root filesystem is beyond the scope of this answer.*

In my opinion, a canonical answer to this fulfills 3 criteria:

- Has the least amount of logical steps
- Adheres to the ZFS design philosophy
- Is resilient across different configurations and distributions

For my proposed answer, I will call the old zpool `oldpool` and the new zpool `newpool`, and the snapshot is called `@today`.

First, create a snapshot of your old zpool/dataset:

```
zfs snap oldpool@today
```

Then, write the snapshot to a file:

```
zfs send -R oldpool@today > gzip /tmp/oldpool.gz
```

Now destroy your old zpool, resize your partitions and create a new one with the parameters you prefer *(not part of the question nor answer)*.

Then mirror the two previous steps, but in reverse order.

Restore snapshot from file:

```
zcat /tmp/oldpool.gz | zfs recv -F newpool@today
```

And finally rollback the snapshot to the new zpool/dataset:

```
zfs rollback newpool@today
```

Now you have restored your zpool dataset to the exact same state as when the snapshot was taken. Data is backed up and restored using snapshots to preserve the filesystem state, and I believe this is the most correct way to handle this.

The above methodology is universally useful for other snapshots and backups as well.